# How to prevent lost focus event get called if window is closing

Tags: c#, wpf, focus

I have written a custom wpf usercontrol which subscribes the `LostFocus` event. But i have the problem, that the event also gets fired if the `UserControl` has focus and the window which contains the control will be closed. I don't want to get the event fired if the window is closing, only if the user select antoher control with the mouse or tab through the ui elements.

**EDIT**

As an important information, i do not have access to the `Window` instance in the user control.

**EDIT 2**

It would be nice if there is a solution which not only work for window closing, as also for closeable TabItems and all similiar things. In general if we could say, if the `UserControl` visibility will be change to not visible.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What problem is this causing?

Comment: I validate the value in the UserControl if the focus is lost. This validation opens another window, which should not if this happens on window closing.

Answer (score 3):

"i do not have access to the Window instance in the user control"

Yes you do:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControlReference);
```

The answer, is in your `UserControl.Loaded`, or wherever else you'd like, you need to use the above code to get a reference to the parent window, and subscribe to the `Closing` event. In the event handler, simply set a local property or something to tell your `LostFocus` method not to continue executing.

Keep in mind, that you need to call the `Window.GetWindow` method **AFTER** your user control has fully loaded. You can **not** use this within the contstructor of your User Control or it will return null. Instead use the `Loaded` event, or similar.

Comment: Thank you, but the question was not good explained. What happens if a have some close able `TabItem` or similiar things. I tried to look for a general solution.